# How do I backup updated and deleted posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want an archive system where if a post is updated its previous version is archived so it can be restored. Same goes for if a recored was deleted it can also be restored by a user.

The user can see all previous updates and go back to them if they want.

I found some gems for this a while back but cant find them again now that I'm looking to implement it. I have found [acts as archival](https://github.com/expectedbehavior/acts_as_archival) but thats all. And it only works for archiving deleted records.

What other gems are out there?

Comment: why not just create an extra table, and store a hash string of the record?

Comment: I would if there weren't already gems that did something similar to this, saving me the hassle of doing it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe paper_trail will do what you want. It tracks changes in a separate table and you can traverse the changes. I have used it and it does the job.

> PaperTrail
>
> Track changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. See how a
>   model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version,
>   or restore it after it has been destroyed.

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Thats it! couldn't find it or remember what it was called. thanks